# How to create/use a shared app group container as cache storage between containing app and it's extension in ios

Tags: ios, caching, watchkit, ios-app-group

Data sharing between app and its extension occurs through common AppGroup. I can use shared app group container as persistant data/file storage. How can I create/use shared app group container as cache storage between a containing app and its extension? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. This is possible.

In the `Capabilities` tab of your main app's target and your WatchKit Extension's target, add an app group, e.g., with the name `group.myWatchDefaults`.

Then you can access the defaults like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.myWatchDefaults"];
```

To add data:

```
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"myBoolVariable"];
```

To retrieve data:

```
 bool watchAppOpenedBefore = [[defaults objectForKey:@"myBoolVariable"] boolValue];
```

Make sure that you use `synchronize`after changing the defaults:

```
[defaults synchronize];
```

Sometimes synchronizing NSUserDefaults between a Watch app and its parent app using App Groups doesn't work when using Xcode's simulators. However, it works on the actual devices (iPhone and Apple Watch). Therefore, this seems to be a bug in the simulator.

Comment: thanks for responding quickly.. but what i meant is, i am using containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: to get url from shared container, that url path is similar to be derived from NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] method right?. if thats so , then how am i able to access NSCacheDirectory (cache storage) using shared container?

Comment: There are no "named" directories in the shared container (like there are with standard directories). As such, you should create your own subdirectories as-needed.